# mvc-3 dropdown binding-razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table in the database called Person and it has various fields like id(Guid), forename and lastname. I am pulling them from the database using the following code

There is a method called GetAll, Which returns the List items.

In controller:

```
            ClassService p= new ClassService();
            ViewData["Id"]= new SelectList(p.GetAll(),"id","Forename");
```

In View:

```
               @Html.DropDownList("Id_0",((SelectList)ViewData["Id"]).Items,"none")
```

It complains that there is acompilation error.What is wrong in there? and if it compiles does it loads into the dropdown box?

Could anybody tell is this correct of doing it or am I missing anything.

Thanks

Comment: What does the compilation error say?

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>, object)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Try removing ".Items" from the SelectList parameter. I

Answer (score 0):

Html.DropDownList() takes the name you want the select to be called and then an IEnumerable of SelectListItem().  Remove the .Item second parameter and it should work.  The third parameter is the value of the selected item.  So I am not sure what passing "none" will do other than not select anything in the dropdown list.

Also I am not sure how you will be handling the binding to a model when you post the form.  Dont forget to have a integer called Id_0 as a parameter to the [HttpPost] action menthod.